# Java: Why does this code give me "generic array creation error"?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, creation

Why does the following code result in a "generic array creation error" at compile time?

```
public class Trie<Value> {
    private class Node {
        private Node[] links = new Node[256];
        private Object val;
    }
}
```

```
Error message: Trie.java:3: error: generic array creation 
        private Node[] links = new Node[256];
```

Comment: btw, if you don't need to access `Trie` fields in `Node`, you can(and should) make it static. And you will be able to create an array of them.